# how to retrive value between double quotes with multiple double quotes in line using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to retrieve value of 'identifier' from below line which is string 'TestStudioJobResponseMessages' in below example, also I don't want to use string uuid in my sed expression as some of the line might not have that.
So ideally what I am looking for is value between 1st pair of double quotes after 'identifier='

```
sed -n 's/.\*identifier=\"\(.\*\)\" .*/\1/p'
```

which would result everything until end of line.

sibresources:SIBQueue xmi:id="SIBQueue_1298124464618" identifier="TestStudioJobResponseMessages" uuid="8CC71271B2F1D3CF65984403" description="" overrideOfQOSByProducerAllowed="true" maxFailedDeliveries="100" exceptionDestination="$DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_DESTINATION" sendAllowed="true" receiveAllowed="true"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be processing an XML file. Use a proper XML handling tool, e.g. [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
register-namespace sr http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/6.0/sibresources.xmi ;
for //sr:SIBQueue echo @identifier ;
```

Comment: Thanks for option, its xml file however using cygwin on windows machine, so xsh won't be there, therefore using cygwin bash shell, and looking for sed alternative

Comment: I'm using cygwin's bash too. `xsh` can be installed by `cpan XML::XSH2` (you need libxml and Perl).

Comment: Thanks however I have to provide script to users who would not want to install xsh/perl so looking for simpler option of using bash

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*identifier="([a-zA-Z]+)".*/\1/'
```

OR

```
sed -r 's/.*identifier="([^"]+)".*/\1/'
```